# In Bash how does one determining the length of filename?

Tags: bash, rename

I'm doing a little script to rename some files. Actually a lot of files.

The problem and the cool thing is, that I actually just need to change the files that have a filename length of 5 characters.

I did a `$(filename:0:5)` and look if there is some leftover, but I guess that's dirty and I would appreciate to know the real or scholastic way of doing this.

Something like that:

```
if [$(filename).length() == 5]; then
  reaname_file
fi
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `${#VAR}` to get the length of a variable `$VAR`:

```
if [ "${#filename}" -eq 5 ]; then
   rename_file
fi
```

Comment: Note that the _length_ is expressed in number of characters with some shells and number of bytes in some others.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Can you explain why you added quotes, please? IMHO `${#..}` should return just a number in all cases.

Comment: Leaving a variable unquoted in the split+glob operator. You want neither here, so it should be quoted as usual. That's not to do with what the variable contains.

Answer (score 6):

```
for file in ?????; do
  something with "$file"
done
```

Will process only the (non-hidden) files in the current directory whose name consists in 5 characters. Note that for some shells like `dash` and some implementations of `ksh`, it is 5 bytes instead of 5 characters which can matter in multi-byte locales.

For those same shells, `${#var}` will expand to the number of bytes in the variable instead of the number of characters.

Answer (score 4):

With bash, you can force an [Arithmetic Context](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression)

```
if (( ${#filename} == 5 )); then
   :
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Say, "filename.txt" is the file then you can use,

```
    file=`echo "fileName.txt" | cut -d'.' -f1`
    if [ ${#file} -ge 5 ]; then
       #you can rename your filename accordingly
    fi
```

Comment: Or even `filename=fileName.txt file=${filename%.*}`

Answer (score -1):

```
if len(file) >= 5 chars
   then ren(file) $_;
end if
```